# Height of water spurt in Heron's fountain

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I'm trying to understand the height of the water spurt in Heron's fountain under ideal conditions (incompressible fluid/gas, no turbulence, no effects of temperature...). Referring to the diagram below, the pressure of the column of water on the left hand side (in the tube connecting A to C) is given by: $F = ma$

$F = h_{1}a_{1} \rho_{w}g$

Where $h_{1}$ is the height of the column, $a_{1}$ is the cross-sectional area of the tube, $\rho_{w}$ the the density of water and $g$ is gravity.

On the right hand side, the force upwards can be described by:
$F = h_{3}a_{3} \rho_{w}g$

As the two sides must be the same we have that: $h_{1}a_{1} \rho_{w}g = h_{3}a_{3} \rho_{w}g$

[I'm assuming that no energy is lost in the connection between C and B and hence the full force in the first tube is transferred to the last one]

We can then solve for $h_{3}$ to find the height of the spurt.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: If my guess is not wrong, the areas of the water surfaces would also matter.

Comment: The height of the spurt should be determined by the pressure at the outlet and properties of the nozzle. Example: Attach a nozzle that emits a horizontal stream and your reasoning falls apart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under ideal conditions, with incompressible water and air and energy conservation, the height $h_3$ is (almost) equal to the height $h_1$. When a certain amount of water descends from A to C, then due to the incompressibility of the air, the same amount of water rises from B. (Almost) All the potential energy released during the descent of water from A to C is transferred to the rise of water from B. Therefore, the same amount of water will rise to (almost) the same height, $h_3 \approx h_1$.

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_fountain), this scenario is real.